# C++ constructors and computed fields

Tags: c++, constructor, factory

In C++, constructors must initialize `const` variables using initialization lists.

What if my constructor needs to compute the values of those fields? Say via a database lookup or simple computation.

The factory pattern could be applied here, but it seems a bit heavy. I'm considering static methods like `X::GetX(param1, param2)` that will compute the values and call a private constructor.

Is there a better or more popular pattern that could be used here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for calling a private constructor, you can call static methods (or in some cases, even non-static ones) directly from the initializer list. For example:

```
class testclass {
    public:
    testclass::testclass(int n): memberdata(fn(n)) { }

    private:
    int fn(int n) {
        // Various calculations on 'n'
        return 12;
    }

    int memberdata;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call static functions within the initialisers, and those functions can contain whatever logic you please.

Comment: That works well enough when each static function provides the value for just one member variable, but sometimes there are situations where the values are interdependent and can't be determined individually.  Normally you could return something like a `std::pair` from a function, but that can't be used to initialize two variables in an initializer list.

Comment: @Wyzard: That reminds me of why I don't use C++ any more: lack of sane multiple-value handling. ;-) (Just kidding, but seriously, Lisp and Scheme handle multiple-values much better than most other languages.)

Comment: @Wyzard: There are ways around that, such as wrapping all the values you need to initialize from a single function into a private `struct` or `boost::tuple` that the function can return. Not always convenient, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method inside the initializer list itself:

```
class A {
public:
  A () : t_Const(X::Get(param1, param2)) { }  // constructor can be public
  const int t_Const;  // this is your variable
};
```

Why you need a private constructor!